# Java compiling: NoClassDefFound & ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, compilation

I am trying to compile my java program using netbeans into a single .jar file, and holds multiple libraries. I am getting the NoClassDefFound & ClassNotFoundException errors when trying to run via the cmd using: java -jar javafile.jar  I have put my lib folder with all libraries inside the 'dist' folder. Here is the error output in the cmd line:

[image]

It is for this particular library however it isn't added any different from the others and it doesn't seem like the others are throwing out errors of the class not being found.

Comment: can you show your code and full CMD command list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to check the manifest file in your JAR file, which contains the classpath.

Try this:

```
jar xvf javafile.jar
```

That should extract the manifest to META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. Look at the MANIFEST.MF file and find the "Class-Path:" entry. Does it contain the JAR file that contains the ZipException class?

Comment: There is no 'Class-path' entry at all..just the version, ant-version, created-by and main-class

Comment: Looks like Netbeans isn't generating the Class-Path entry for some reason. I can't be of too much help here as I know next to nothing about Netbeans.

Comment: can I just add it myself, and how would I do this considering I have multiple libraries?

Comment: You could just add it yourself, yes, but this may be a bit difficult to maintain if you're rebuilding the JAR. According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR%20Manifest multiple URLs in the Class-Path attribute are separate by spaces.